# Product image in product list page should link to product-view page

Tags: product-list, product-view

please visit this link : http://gas1.newtrendzonline.com/index.php/shop-for-products.html

here, only by clicking on products name, we can view "products-view" page.

what I need is ,If we click on "Products-images" , it should link "products-view" page.

this is list.phtml => http://pastebin.com/qkrUmmGR

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code for link to product view page.

I have check your structure. When you hover the Image then one layer will be coming so we need to give url to that link.

```
<div class="product-inner" onClick="window.open('<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>');">
     <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
           <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
           <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="product-des">
                    <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescriptionGrid(), 'short_description_grid') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="actions">
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>

                    <?php else: ?>
                        <li><p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>


                    </ul>
       <div class="price-box-item">
    </div>
```

**More Focus on line no one `<div class="product-inner" onClick="window.open('<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>');">`.**